# Is there a "base64.b85decode" equivalent in NodeJS?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, encoding, radix

Is there a "[base64.b85decode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html#base64.b85encode)" function in nodejs?
It uses the following character set -

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
!#$%&()*+-;<=>?@^_`{|}~
```

It's not a regular Ascii85 encoding but a different base85 encoding type.

For example, for "*Hello, world!!!!*", It should return "*NM&qnZ!92pZ*pv8At50l"

Comment: There is the [base85](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base85) package.

Comment: Nothing native but ton of packages you can install.

Comment: @RobC When using the base85 package, it doesn't use the right encoding.. "Hello, world!!!!" = "nm=QNz.92Pz/PV8aT50L" instead of "NM&qnZ!92pZ*pv8At50l"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the ascii85 package and using a customized character set -

```
var ascii85 = require('ascii85');
ascii85.decode(to_decode, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+', '-', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']).toString('ascii');
```